# How do I select Lat & Long coordinates back out of SQL Server Geography data type field

Tags: sql, sqlgeography

Considering the SQL Server 'geography' data type...

I can enter an array of latitude and longitude (btw is that the correct order to do so or should it be longitude latitude?) points into the field as follows:

```
INSERT INTO SpatialZonePolygons (Coordinates)
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653 , -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326));
GO
```

This then appears as:

```
0xE6100000010405000000DD24068195D34740F4FDD478E9965EC0508D976E12D3474083C0CAA145965EC04E62105839D4474083C0CAA145965EC04E62105839D44740F4FDD478E9965EC0DD24068195D34740F4FDD478E9965EC001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003
```

How do I select them back into their latitude and longitude formats?

Comment: [`STAsText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933970.aspx)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Select convert(varchar(max),Coordinates) as Coordinates from SpatialZonePolygons ;
```

take a look here for more information - [SQL Server Geography Data Type](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1965/sql-server-geography-data-type/)

Answer (score 22):

You may use something like this(SQL SERVER)

```
SELECT Coordinates.Lat 'Latitude', Coordinates.Long 'Longitude' FROM SpatialZonePolygons
```

For more information - [How To Get Lat-Long From Geography Data Type](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5cc4cdf3-d882-4342-9ff4-525e17fd8a3f/how-to-get-latlong-from-geography-data-type?forum=sqlspatial)